# Can't connect to Wifi from recovery mode in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

I made all steps: wrote my key and ssid to /etc/network/interfaces, turn wlp3s0 up, and using iwconfig tryed to connect, by using command "iwconfig wlp3s0 essid name key s:password", but its always error:"SET failed on device wlp3s0; Invalid argument."  I couldn't do it not from recovery mode cause I'm accidentally deleted "etc/share" folder, so if you know, please help!

Answer (score 0):

These links helped me with a similar issue:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2164398

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/connect-wifi-terminal-ubuntu-16-04/

"iwconfig" for WEP.
"key s:password" is used if your password is in ASCII. 
If your password is in HEX, you use "key password".

Also, "wpasupplicant" for WPA.

Hope you are well!